# UserInputPanel Radio Button ignoring conditionid value izpack

Tags: izpack

I'm running the installer in debug mode and I want to hide a radio button based on a condition. 
The value of the conditions are correct but my panel is ignoring the conditions and showing all of the radio buttons.

```
<condition type="variable" id="gains.show.radio.custom.passwords">
    <name>show.radio.custom.passwords</name>
    <value>true</value>
</condition>
<condition type="variable" id="gains.show.radio.default.passwords">
    <name>show.radio.default.passwords</name>
    <value>true</value>
</condition>

<!-- Variables to control which radio buttons are shown for password options-->         
<variable name="show.radio.custom.passwords" value="false" />
<variable name="show.radio.default.passwords" value="true" />

<panel order="15">
<field size="2" txt="Password Options" type="title" />
<field align="top" type="divider" />
<field type="radio" variable="gains.radio.password.selection">
    <description align="left" txt="Choose password option:" />
    <spec>
        <choice txt="Use Gains preset default users passwords" value="default passwords selected" conditionid="gains.show.radio.default.passwords"/> 
        <choice txt="Use custom set passwords" value="use custom passwords" set="true" conditionid="gains.show.radio.custom.passwords" /> 
        <choice txt="Reset Gains default users passwords" value="reset passwords selected"/>
    </spec>
</field>
<field align="bottom" type="divider" />
</panel>
```